# I've facing some problems with <ion-content> tag and <ion-tab> tag

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, indentation

I've facing some problems with these tags, it's been 4 days in which I'm trying to create an app that shows some courses (clickable) using cards. Problem is that when i put things in ion-content tag separately, the disappear! Meanwhile, when i put them in, problems come talking about tab-bar, in fact it doesn't stick on the botton, even tho i use "slot='bottom'". I put some code and show you. Could you give me some tips to upgrade my skills with ionic and angular? Those would be appreciated.

home.page.html

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-nav>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>Bacheca corsi</ion-title>
    </ion-nav>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="corsi-consigliati" *ngIf="corsi.length">
    <ion-slides pager>
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let corso of corsi" (click)="apriCorso(corso)">

        <img [src]="corso.immagine"/>
        <div class="corso-titolo" text-wrap>{{corso.nome}}</div>

      </ion-slide>  
    </ion-slides>
  </div>
  <ion-grid fixed>
    <ion-row class="singolaMattonella ion-justify-content-start">

      <ion-col class="doppiaMattonella"  *ngFor="let i of corsi"  size="5" size-xs="6" size-sm="5" size-md="4" size-lg="3">
        <ion-card (click)="apriCorso(i)">
          <img [src]="i.immagine"/>
          <ion-card-content class="scritto">
            <h5 text-nowrap text-center>
              {{i.nome}}
            </h5>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

  <ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">

      <ion-tab-button tab="Profilo">
        <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Account</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="Corsi">
        <ion-icon name="book"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Corsi</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>


      <ion-tab-button tab="Notizie">
        <ion-icon name="people"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Bacheca</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="Preferiti">
        <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Preferiti</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="Impostazioni">
        <ion-icon name="cog"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Impostazioni</ion-label>
      </ion-tab-button>

    </ion-tab-bar>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

home.page.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Corso } from '../corsi';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  corsi: Corso[] = [ // array di corsi prendendo come interfaccia il model corsi.ts
    new Corso(1, "Eipass Basic", "Certificazione Informatica", 15, 15, "assets/images/cucinaThai.jpg", "prova1", "o"),
    new Corso(2, "Eipass Basic 7 Moduli User", "Certificazione Informatica", 15, 15, "assets/images/cucinaThai.jpg", "prova1", "o"),
    new Corso(3, "Eipass Progressive", "Certificazione Informatica", 15, 15, "assets/images/cucinaThai.jpg", "prova1", "o"),
    new Corso(4, "Master Io livello", "Master Universitario", 5, 5, "assets/images/python.jpg", "prova2", "f"),
    new Corso(5, "Master IIo livello", "Master Universitario", 5, 5, "assets/images/python.jpg", "prova2", "f"),
    new Corso(6, "Inglese", "Certificazione Linguistica", 5, 5, "assets/images/python.jpg", "prova2", "f")
  ];//i tipi di corso sono 3

  constructor(nav: NavController) {}

  apriCorso(i){
    alert("ciao");
  }
}
```

home.page.scss

```
.iniziale .corsi-consigliati {
    position: relative;
  }

  .iniziale .corsi-consigliati .corso-titolo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 60px;
  }

  .iniziale .doppiaMattonella:not(:last-child) ion-col {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .iniziale .singolaMattonella ion-card {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
  }

  .iniziale .singolaMattonella ion-card img {
    max-height: 150px;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a 4months old question, but I found it while looking at something else.

I think you solved your problem since you asked, but for future people seeing this, here is some help:

when you use `<ion-tabs>`, its content is shown on top of everything in . What you need to do is only use your `<ion-tabs>` inside your `<ion-content>` and create a component that shows your page to act as your first tab.

Here some exemple from ionic documentation:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs#usage

Don't forget angular routing configuration for tabs components: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs#router-integration